# Correct syntax for calling rest API using jQuery

Tags: jquery, rest

I'm calling a rest API provided by 2Checkout.  Here's my code

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: "application/json",
    accepts: {json:"application/json"},
    url: "https://api.2checkout.com/rest/5.0/subscriptions/9C77B952C2/",
    success: function(data){
    },
    error: function(){
    }
  });
```

When I execute this code I get the error:  `net::ERR_ABORTED 415`

When I try to open the URL in a new tab I get:

```
{"error_code":"INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE","message":"The current resource can not be served as [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, image/webp, image/apng, */*;q=0.8] content-types"}
```

So based on that I figured I need to specify the correct content type to be accepted by the server, which is why I added:

```
 accepts: {json:"application/json"},
```

2Checkout support tells me `"when using REST API make sure that http header also contains “Accept: application/json”. This is mandatory for the call to work and for retrieving info."`

But their only example is raw javascript, not jQuery.  The javascript example looks like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'https://api.2checkout.com/rest/5.0/subscriptions/{SubscriptionReference}/');

request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log('Status:', this.status);
    console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
  }
};

request.send();
```

So I'd like to make this work in jQuery if possible, and I feel like it shouldn't be this difficult yet I keep getting the error.

Unfortunately the jquery documentation is not very specific and only gives an example of a custom type, which I don't think this would be.  Also it says that the default value for "accepts" depends on the datatype, which in my case is jsonp, so I would assume then that it automatically accepts application/json, yet it does not.

What's the trick here?

Comment: You can't set headers like this on a `jsonp` request, as far as I know. Are you sure that API is accepting jsonp requests? That vanilla JS sample looks like normal JSON call to me. In which case `dataType: "json"` should be enough in itself.

Comment: hm.. I did as you suggested and now I get a 405 error.   "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."